# parallel PBI in UAT Environment using git

Tags: git, merge, branch, workflow, uat

Our company has about 20 git repositories, each of them is for a specific service. Now when we want to add a feature, some of these repositories might change altogether.

for example adding feature like
`addSecurePayment` might change:

```
[repository1, respository2, repository3]
```

and adding feature like 
`addGoogleAuth` might change:

```
[repository2, respository3, repository4]
```

we have 4 different environments, `dev`, `UAT`, `test`, and `prod`.

so each of these 20 service repositories has 4 main branches, `dev`, `UAT`, `test`, and `prod`.

The question is nowadays business needs parallel feature testing at the same time, for example, one-week UAT for `addSecurePayment` and at the same time one-week UAT for `addGoogleAuth`, then each of them will be added into prod environment.

In the past, we had enough time to have one week UAT for each of these features, then merge the feature and have UAT week for next feature, but nowadays, we don't. How can we have multiple PBI test at UAT at the same time? Which git workflow should we have, and what kind of structure?